# Min/Max Currency Field

Tags: angularjs, angular-formly

Take a look at this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/bapezahawo/edit?js,output)

I have one field that is properly checking the range of the user's input.  This is a number field.

I have another field that is changing the input into a currency format.  This is a text field.

My issue is that I cannot do both of these ideas on one field.  One field needs it to be text while the other requires it to be a number.

Is there something out there that can accomplish the marriage of both fields?

Comment: Post your code here, please.

Comment: You can implement a filter and use a text field for both.

Comment: @EdCottrell I'm not going to post all of my code.  Would make the question gigantic and confusing for no reason.

Comment: In that case, your question is going to be closed. Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Fals Do you have an example of this?  I couldn't get the filter to work on the textbox while still letting it do range validation

Comment: Fine, i'll keep it in mind for future questions.

Comment: check model value not view value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of creating your own directive look into ng-currency: http://ngmodules.org/modules/ng-currency

```
<input type="text" model="yourModel" ng-currency min="1" max="1337" />
```

```js
angular.module('myApp', ['ng-currency'])
  .controller('CurrencyController', function($scope) {
    $scope.myData = 8;
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/aguirrel/ng-currency/master/src/ng-currency.js"></script>

<!-- PLEASE CHANGE AS YOU WISH THIS LOCALE JS -->
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/i18n/angular-locale_es-us.js"></script>


<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="CurrencyController">
  <input type="text" ng-model="myData" ng-currency min="1" max="10" currency-symbol="$" /><br/>
  {{ myData }}
</div>
```

Comment: Does ng-currency let me do range validation while also converting a field into currency?  I saw that it def helps with the converting but I thought it still suffered from the inability of validation a min/max value range.

Comment: Did you read the github page it says it does. I just did a plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/GBpirTf28RDPg2uXT1un  and it does have a min max but it works by setting the model to empty. If that is not what you want I would add https://github.com/turinggroup/angular-validator for the min and max validators. I am not a fan of ng-messages as angular-validator is much more clean and functional.

Comment: Great.  Thanks for the help man!  Not sure how I missed the min/max for ngcurrency.